# simple way to view a depth image topic from command line?

Tags: ros, rqt-image-view, image-view, depth-image, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

image_view pukes when you try to view a depth image (typically 16 bit single channel):

$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/hsrb/head_rgbd_sensor/depth_registered/image_raw
[ INFO] [1439901837.964462440]: Using transport "raw"
[ERROR] [1439901838.243159831]: Unable to convert '16UC1' image to bgr8: '[16UC1] is not a color format. but [bgr8] is. The conversion does not make sense'

all of the rqt stuff works, but it all seems to require you to launch a gui and use the mouse to mess around with widgets to view any given topic.

Is there something that ships with ROS that I can just run from the command line to view a depth image topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216039/simple-way-to-view-a-depth-image-topic-from-command-line?/) by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2015-08-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on 2015-08-18**:
Note, I can and did hack together my own crappy version of image_view, but there has to be a better way.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-08-18**:
Have you tried `rqt_image_view`?

**Comment by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) on 2015-09-10**:
Hi Dirk, I haven't figured out how to launch rqt_image_view from the command line so that it just displays what I want;  always have to use the mouse.  I am caring less and less, though; I spend so much time debugging ros connections that it is better to use the mouse and leave rqt open. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The latest code of `rqt_image_view` allows passing a command line argument with the topic name (https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/commit/13f3fee3ee0ff0769ef8dde72cea6def370f7aed). This change has not been released yet but will likely be released in the next couple of weeks.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-11-21**:
Should `rqt_image_view /image_raw` or similar work now?  It doesn't for me in Ubuntu 14.04 Jade

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-04-12**:
A new release of this repo was done early March 2016: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/commit/c1cbb37189b7cd47cedbf9a975416c625f83b4a5